# How to abort a gesture in iOS?

Tags: ios, gesture, uipageviewcontroller

everyone

I noticed that in the following document, gestures can be aborted. I want to abort the gesture at this point: pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDelegate.html

But, I don't know how to do that. Can someone tell how?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegate method mentioned below. When you can make a check if touched view is the one with link. Return Yes or No accordingly in this delegate method.

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Although, I still don't know how to 'abort' gestures.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the gesture recognizer and then use `recognizer.enabled = NO;` to disable it and cancel any in progress gesture. Set it back to `YES` when you're ready (which could be immediately).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, I want to disable tap gesture temporarily if the clicked region contains a link (in order to open the link), else behaves normally.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIPageViewController` implements a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. If you want to disable any gesture recognizers, you can do that by iterating through its `gestureRecognizers` property which returns the array

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers)
{
  if([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
  {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *rec = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
        [rec setEnabled:NO];
  }
}
```

You can check for the next view controller in the `UIPageViewController`'s delegate method `pageViewController:willTransitionToViewControllers:` and disable the `UITapGestureRecognizer` for any particular view controller and enable it again after it has been out of view.